# Bamboo Agent: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3

Tags: android, makefile, bamboo, android-build, android-sdk-manager

I use a pool of Linux agents to build my app. Every now and then an agent causes a build failure with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ComponentThatReqBuildToolsRev23.0.3:preBuild'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
```

Because my build agents are remote (android is pre-installed /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android), I cannot preinstall the platform tools, build tools etc so have have a makefile included with my project. After checking out the code, it calls a method in the makefile:

```
#!/bin/bash
git submodule init
git submodule update
make updateSDK
# EOF
```

The method in the makefile is:

```
PACKAGES = "tools,platform-tools,build-tools-21.1.2,android-22,build-tools-23.0.3,android-21,extra-android-support,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google,google_play_services"

updateSDK:
    (sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done) \
        | android --clear-cache update sdk --no-ui --all \
        --filter $(PACKAGES)
```

In successful cases, the log from Bamboo shows:

```
Refresh Sources:
Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Refresh Sources
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
\Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Validate XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml

License id: android-sdk-license-c81a61d9
Used by: 
- Android SDK Tools, revision 25.1.3
- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 23.1
- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2
- SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2
- SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
- Android Support Repository, revision 30
- Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1 (Obsolete)
- Google Play services, revision 29
- Google Repository, revision 25
...
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]: 
y'. (There's a few of these)
Lots of lines of install code....

Finished task 'Update Android SDK' with result: Success
```

But every now and then, it connects to the wrong repository, either:

```
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
```

or

```
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml
```

It's identical to the above log except for the url. It gives this error:

```
Error: Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.3'
```

In these cases, the xml file does not contain build tools 23.0.3, i.e. this bit:

```
<sdk:archive>
<!--Built on: Tue Mar 15 17:38:51 2016.-->
<sdk:size>40733174</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">368f2600feac7e9b511b82f53d1f2240ae4a91a3</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip</sdk:url>
<sdk:host-os>linux</sdk:host-os>
</sdk:archive><sdk:archive>
<!--Built on: Tue Mar 15 17:38:50 2016.-->
<sdk:size>39679533</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">fbc98cd303fd15a31d472de6c03bd707829f00b0</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>build-tools_r23.0.3-macosx.zip</sdk:url>
<sdk:host-os>macosx</sdk:host-os></sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive>
<!--Built on: Tue Mar 15 17:38:48 2016.-->
<sdk:size>39869945</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">c6d8266c6a3243c8f1e41b786c0e3cee4c781263</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>build-tools_r23.0.3-windows.zip</sdk:url>
<sdk:host-os>windows</sdk:host-os>
</sdk:archive>
```

I've tried clearing the cache on the agent pre-build, I've tried listing the tools each time, used http and https and to no avail.

Basically my question is, where does the android update sdk command get the repository-XX.xml url from? Can you force this to the latest version?

Comment: Have you verified the configuration of all your remote build machines such that your remote capabilities are correct? If you inadvertently tell Bamboo that all your remote agents have certain capabilities, then it will build on those that match its needs. If any of those agents actually lack the underlying tools, or are misconfigured "below" the agent level, you will get build fails.

Comment: To further expand: verify that each remote agent is identical in configuration. That's where Docker, for instance, makes for a great build environment - you know that all containers will be identical.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Marakai. The agents are managed by an internal dev ops team and all have exactly the same image reloaded daily so the configuration shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: When you do get a failure, does it tend to be with the same URL? Or will it be one that worked "just a second" ago, then fails, then it may work again? What I'm getting at is that if it's consistent you may try blacklisting.

Comment: That is quite a good idea @Marakai. Let me see what I come up with.